# I am reading contacts from my phone book,but is it possible to read the numbers which is greater than 10 digit

Tags: android, android-studio, android-contacts

I am reading contacts from my phone book,but is it possible to read the numbers which is greater than 10 digit

String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

Comment: yes it will through what ever number it found, doesn't matter the number length.

Comment: Is it possible to keep the number length as mininum 10,otherwise if the number is below 10 digit   not displaying it in the list

Comment: Simple get length of that string and don't add it in list if number is lessthan 10.